# How to access the window object from the document object

Tags: javascript, window, document, frames

Is it possible to access the window object directly from the document object in Javascript?

For example:

```
// window.frames[0] returns the document object of the first frame or iframe found on the page
myFunc(window.frames[0]);

function myFunc(doc) {
  // I want to do something along these lines:
  var wnd = doc.getWindow();
  alert("Found frame: " + wnd.name);
  for (var i=0; i<wnd.frames.length; i++) {
    myFunc(wnd.frames[i]);
  }
}
```

I can't use jQuery for this, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.frames) you should already be getting the window with `window.frames[0]`.  If you want the actual document you need to grab the actual frame element and dig into the document.

```
var firstFrame = document.getElementsByTagName( "iframe" )[ 0 ];
firstFrame.contentWindow;  // The window
firstFrame.contentWindow.document;  // The document
```

Note: I believe `contentWindow` isn't supported in very early versions of Safari (pre-3.0 IIRC)

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the case.  Try the example code I gave in my question with `contentWindow` and you'll find it doesn't work, certainly not in all browsers.

Comment: @NickBrunt according to the MDN documentation the result of `windows.frames[0]` should be the `contentWindow`.  There is a difference between `window.frames[0]` and `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]`

Comment: There is a major difference between what *should* happen and what *does* happen.  Try it for yourself.

Comment: If it works, can you please answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528857/how-to-attach-submit-listener-to-all-forms-including-those-in-iframes-and-nested ?

Comment: @NickBrunt have you tried my sample code to see if it will give you a DOM element?

Comment: @NickBrunt it works fine in Chrome for me.  Which part is not functioning?